# Python ReLu activation function desn't work

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, relu

My first neural network was using sigmoid activation function and was working fine. Now I want to switch to more advanced activation function(ReLu). But with ReLu my NN doesn't work at all. 90% of errors, while using sigmoid there were 4% of errors. I can't find bug in code. Help me.

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate = 0.1):
        self.input_nodes = input_nodes
        self.hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes
        self.output_nodes = output_nodes
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.weights_ih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(input_nodes, -0.5), (hidden_nodes, input_nodes))
        self.weights_ho = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(hidden_nodes, -0.5), (output_nodes, hidden_nodes))
        self.bias_h = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(1, -0.5), (hidden_nodes, 1))
        self.bias_o = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(1, -0.5), (output_nodes, 1))

    def activation_function(self, x):
        return x * (x > 0)

    def activation_function_d(self, x):
        return 1 * (x >= 0)

    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

        # Feedforward
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h
        hidden = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
        output_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o
        outputs = self.activation_function(output_inputs)

        # Calculate errors
        output_errors = targets - outputs
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.weights_ho.T, output_errors)

        # Calculate gradients
        output_gradient = output_errors * self.activation_function_d(output_inputs) * self.learning_rate
        hidden_gradient = hidden_errors * self.activation_function_d(hidden_inputs) * self.learning_rate

        # Calculate deltas
        output_deltas = np.dot(output_gradient, hidden.T)
        hidden_deltas = np.dot(hidden_gradient, inputs.T)

        # Adjust weights and biases by deltas and gradients
        self.weights_ho += output_deltas
        self.weights_ih += hidden_deltas
        self.bias_o     += output_gradient
        self.bias_h     += hidden_gradient

    def predict(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden = self.activation_function(np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h)
        outputs = self.activation_function(np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o)
        return outputs.flatten().tolist()
```

And training code:

```
with open('mnist_train.csv') as train_file:
    for str in train_file:
        data = [int(char) for char in str.split(',')]
        inputs = data[1:]
        targets = [1 if i == data[0] else 0 for i in range(10)]
        nn.train(inputs, targets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last layer should always use sigmoid (in the binary case) regardless of what you are trying to do.

The sigmoid function is used to estimate the **probabilities** that an example is in a given class, the prediction of an example is the class which the example has the highest probability to be in.

To conclude, change this:

```
def predict(self, inputs_list):
    inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    hidden = self.activation_function(np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h)
    outputs = self.activation_function(np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o)
    return outputs.flatten().tolist()
```

to this

```
def predict(self, inputs_list):
    inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    hidden = self.activation_function(np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h)
    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o) // create a sigmoid function
    return outputs.flatten().tolist()
```

and in the training:

```
    # Feedforward
    hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h
    hidden = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
    output_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o
    outputs = self.activation_function(output_inputs)
```

to:

```
    # Feedforward
    hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs) + self.bias_h
    hidden = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
    output_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden) + self.bias_o
    outputs = sigmoid(output_inputs)
```

and

```
    # Calculate gradients
    output_gradient = output_errors * self.activation_function_d(output_inputs) * self.learning_rate
    hidden_gradient = hidden_errors * self.activation_function_d(hidden_inputs) * self.learning_rate
```

to

```
       # Calculate gradients
    output_gradient = output_errors * sigmoid_d(output_inputs) * self.learning_rate
    hidden_gradient = hidden_errors * self.activation_function_d(hidden_inputs) * self.learning_rate
```

Comment: Why do you use sigmoid on hidden layer and relu on output layer when calculating gradients?

Comment: If I use sigmoid then I should normalize targets to range (0, 1), right? And should I normalize inputs to some range if I use ReLu?

Comment: Try the same range, from my experience it works well though i don't think ReLU requires normalizing to a specific range

Comment: I replaced ReLu with sigmoid on output layer but got 30% of errors, after second training I got 50% of errors. Then switched again to sigmoid and got 6% of errors. Can you look at my code? Thak you anyway. [GitHub](https://github.com/olegmisar/python-neural-network)